# How do I run a linear regression between certain observations in a data set?

Tags: r, linear-regression

my problem is that I am unable to run a linear regression between say the 450th and 500th observations of NBA salaries (the salaries only in the year 18/19 in my continuous data set).

So far I have this code:

```
 lm(log(Salary) ~ Twitter + Insta + Age + PPG + APG + RPG + SPG + 
       BPG + MPPG + FG + THREEPG + FT, 
       data = subset(Econ_III_Data_Set1, Year = 18/19))
```

But it is giving the same results as it would if I ran a linear regression on all salaries, not just the ones in the year 18/19 (or the 450th to 500th observations of salaries).

Comment: Use brackets to subset. `Econ_III_Data_Set1[Econ_III_Data_Set1$Year == "18/19", ].`

Comment: How about `data = Econ_III_Data_Set1[450:500,]`

Answer (score 0):

`lm` has a subset argument built in:

```
lm(log(Salary) ~ Twitter + Insta + Age + PPG + APG + RPG + SPG + 
       BPG + MPPG + FG + THREEPG + FT, 
       data = Econ_III_Data_Set1,
       subset = Year == "18/19")
```